# MySQL composite index do not work, unless specified explicitly

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with three columns, let's say they are A, B and C. Each column is indexed by it's own separate index. I was trying to do the following query:

```
select MainTable.* from MainTable
-- And here are some additional joins
WHERE A = <value A> and B = <value B> and C = <value C>
-- and some additional filterings
```

I noticed that the time of query grows proportional to the number of columns involved in filtering. That is, if I filter just by A, it runs for 0.5 seconds. If I filter by A and B, it runs for 0.4 second (because the table is really large). If I filter by A,B and C, it runs for 0.8 seconds, and this is not appropriate.

So I created a composite index on (A,B,C) and ran this again. However, it still ran slow, since for some reason MySQL preferred to use the single-column indices and not the new one, until finally I did a query like this:

```
select MainTable.* from MainTable use index MyNewIndex
-- And here are some additional joins
WHERE A = <value A> and B = <value B> and C = <value C>
-- and some additional filterings
```

Here, everything runs pretty quickly, but the problem is, that I cannot specify such  at application level (the query builder I have simply does not support this thing). So, how do I make mysql use this index? Just remove the single-column indices? But will the other queries that used filtering just by one of these columns work as fast as they did before?

Comment: One of your single column indexes has become redundant (the one on the 1-st column of the composite) and you can drop it. This may or may not fix the problem. Try running `analyze table <table>`, MySQL sometimes gets its statistics wrong when you alter. Also a query plan (`EXPLAIN <query>`) will help a lot in determining whats going on.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the datatypes of A, B, and C may be relevant!

Comment: Are all of A, B, and C in `maintable`?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` say in each case?